# simple flow control with mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I've simple example to describe my problem. Lets say I've table structured like this =>

```
create table A(
id INT(3) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY_KEY,
act DATETIME,
act_reset INT(1) DEFAULT 0);
```

I want to write query with condition that if act_reset is `true` (so if not 0) then update column `act` DATETIME.

I've tried it like this=>

```
IF act_reset THEN UPDATE A SET act=now() WHERE id=1 END IF;
```

but this syntax is not valid, how I must write this condition with one query ? thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
UPDATE A SET act=now() WHERE id=1 AND act_reset <> 0
```

Is this the query you are looking for?

Using If statement in MySQL :

```
IF act_reset <> 0 THEN 
  UPDATE A SET act=now() WHERE id=1 
END IF;
```

Comment: yes it is , but interested with if statement too , because I'm just a begginer at MySql and wanted to know , thanks for advice

Comment: @Tornike Doing it with an `IF` statement is just wrong in SQL. It doesn't make sense. Always try and formulate your question in terms of the set of data that you want to work on - don't think in terms of control flow (i.e. think set-based, not imperative).

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use the `CASE` statement or the `IF` statement in this case. Just move the condition `If act_reset` to the `WHERE` clause, like this:

```
UPDATE A 
SET act = now() 
WHERE id = 1
AND act_reset <> 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `act_reset` is a variables name. You forgot `semicolon`, also you need to use `DELIMITER`

```
DELIMITER $$
IF act_reset <> 0 
THEN 
    UPDATE A SET act=now()
    WHERE id = 1 $$ 
END IF$$
DELIMITER ;
```

If `act_reset` is a column name then in that case it's not possible with IF clause instead try this:

```
    UPDATE A 
    SET act = now()
    WHERE id = 1 AND
          act_reset <> 0;
```